# How do you create a subclass of PropertySourcesPropertyResolver in spring 4?

Tags: spring

I'm trying to figure out a way to store certain properties in an encrypted form while they are at rest, and have them transparently decrypted before the property is injected into any beans, whether they are using @Value or they are defined in xml by setting properties.  We're not using spring-boot yet.  The property file would look like this:

```
db_password={aes}some_encrypted_value
```

I can see in the logs where the `PropertySourcesPropertyResolver` gets the value for my property.  It should be pretty simple to create my own implementation of the `PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty` method that looks for the "{aes}" prefix, decrypting it if necessary, but I can't figure out how to use my subclass in my application.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get spring to use my implementation instead of Springs?

I initially tried to use the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` that worked for me in Spring 3, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work in spring 4.  I also couldn't get the newer `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to work either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did it as follows with Spring 4.0.3 RELEASE

```
public class MyPropertyConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer{
   protected void convertProperties(Properties props){
        Enumeration<?> propertyNames = props.propertyNames();
        while(propertyNames.hasMoreElements()){
          String propName = (String)propertyNames.nextElement();
          String propValue = (String)props.getProperty(propName);
          if(propName.indexOf("db_password") != -1){
             setPropertyValue(props,propName,propValue);  
          }  
      } 
   }

   private void setPropertyValue(Properties props,String propName,String propValue){
       String decryptedValue = PasswordUtility.decrypt(propValue);
       props.setProperty(propName,decryptedValue);
   }
}
```

In xml, it was configured as below

```
<bean id="dbPropertyPlaceholder" class="mypackage.MyPropertyConfigurer">
   <property name="locations">
          <list>
            <value>file:myProp.properties</value>
          <list> 
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This solution pointed me in the right direction.  I had overridden the`convertPropertyValue` method, which worked in Spring 3, but not Spring 4.  For spring 4, I needed to override the `convertProperties` method, which can then call `convertPropertyValue`.

I also extended the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` class, since that seems to be the preferred implementation for Spring 4 and up.